# Add filter to Orderby Parameter using Array

Tags: wp-query, filters, order

Using WP-Query, I'm setting the Orderby parameter using an array:

```
$events_args = array(
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type' => 'events',
    'meta_key' => 'start_time',
    'meta_type' => 'DATETIME',
    'orderby' => array( 'meta_value_num' => 'DESC', 'title' => 'ASC' ),
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'       => 'event_date',
            'compare'   => '=',
            'value'     => 20150225,
        )
      )
);
```

I need to filter the first item in the array (`meta_value_num`). Using `add_filter` , how can I access the first item of the Orderby array to make the adjustments I need?

Thank you!

Comment: I think `pre_get_posts` will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks karpstrucking,

This was a simple case of me needing to understand the Query better. Once I fully understood that `wp_query` returns a string for the sql query, it was a simply case of doing what I needed to do to correction the `event_date` value, concatenating on the additional `title` or `meta_num_value` and returning that.

Then I would just have to `add_filter` the `orderby`.

Comment: You can post your working code as an EDIT to your answer and accept your own answer.